# PrinterWriter creates a file but does not write to it. Tried flush and close everywhere. Still, does not write to file

Tags: java

Tried to put  flush and close everywhere. Still, does not write to file. Changed file location, path of the file, still does not write to the file; however it creates it.

```
public void filePatient(HashMap<Integer,Patient> collection, String filename) {
    // crating a file
    File file = new File (filename+".txt");
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file),true)) {
        for(Patient i: collection.values()) {
            out.write(i.getName());
            //out.write(i.getHealthNumber());
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the map `collection` is not empty? Add a print statement to print the contents of `collection` to verify it

Comment: The code you posted does not behave as described. Either it creates and writes to the file or the collection is empty or you ran out of disk space or something else unstated here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code works as-is.
You can also remove the close, as you use try-with-resources.

Here's a full working example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", "my name");
        map.put("b", "your name");

        filePatient(map, "c:\\temp\\test");
    }

    public static void filePatient(Map<String, String> collection, String filename) {
        // crating a file
        File file = new File(filename + ".txt");
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file), true)) {
            for (String name : collection.values()) {
                out.write(name);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP does call flush and close after the *for* loop

Comment: I probably missed it when copying your code before it was formatted. In that case, it just works as-is for me.